# Should the treatment effect coefficient in a difference-in-difference model be consistent with graph trend?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I am running a difference-in-difference regression and the coefficient of the interaction term (treat*post) is negative, so I concluded that the effect of the treatment was negative on the outcome *logweekwage*. However, when I plot the outcome of the treatment group versus that of the control, I see that relative to the control group, the outcome of the treatment group is increasing (plot below).

[image]

Is this possible? What can be the intuitive explanation for this? Or is there a possible error I made?

Edit: Based on the comments, here are some clarifications:

1. Here's the R code for the DiD regression

```
data$treat <- ifelse(data$status==4, 1, 0)
data$post <- ifelse(data$YEAR>2012, 1, 0)
data$treat_post <- data$treat*data$post

model1 <- lm(logweekwage ~ treat_post + treat + post + factor(industry) + factor(schl) + Exp_1 + Exp_2 + Exp_3 + Exp_4 + Birth81 + Birth78_81 + Birth75_78 + Birth72_75 + Birth69_72 + factor(YEAR), data=data)
```

2. Here's the code for the graph

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(foreign)
library(haven)

data %>%
group_by(YEAR,treat) %>%
summarize(logweekwage=mean(logweekwage)) -> sumdata

ggplot() + 
geom_line(data=sumdata,aes(x=YEAR,y=logweekwage,group=treat, color=as.factor(treat)),
size=2) + 
geom_vline(xintercept = 2012)
```

Edit 2: Here's the original regression result:

```
Call:
lm(formula = logweekwage ~ treat_post + treat + post + factor(industry) + 
    factor(schl) + Exp_1 + Exp_2 + Exp_3 + Exp_4 + Birth81 + 
    Birth78_81 + Birth75_78 + Birth72_75 + Birth69_72 + factor(YEAR), 
    data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-10.0076  -0.3794   0.0784   0.4749   6.0935 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                    Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         6.085862   0.002156 2822.150  < 2e-16 ***
treat_post         -0.030732   0.007619   -4.034 5.49e-05 ***
treat               0.071502   0.005935   12.047  < 2e-16 ***
post                0.023456   0.001088   21.557  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)2  -0.285448   0.002059 -138.634  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)3   0.352151   0.002109  166.983  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)4  -0.073209   0.001983  -36.913  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)5   0.324650   0.002111  153.808  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)6   0.287464   0.002418  118.898  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)7   0.352163   0.002026  173.830  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)8   0.753127   0.003359  224.237  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)9   0.216080   0.002040  105.928  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)10  0.273959   0.002148  127.523  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)11 -0.110324   0.002033  -54.266  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)12  0.266171   0.002200  120.968  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)13  0.596995   0.002920  204.423  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)14  0.309342   0.002321  133.306  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)15 -0.186528   0.002204  -84.615  < 2e-16 ***
factor(industry)16  0.464145   0.003025  153.413  < 2e-16 ***
factor(schl)2       0.306729   0.001017  301.627  < 2e-16 ***
factor(schl)3       0.508816   0.001057  481.481  < 2e-16 ***
factor(schl)4       1.059399   0.001066  993.332  < 2e-16 ***
Exp_1              -0.616021   0.001825 -337.613  < 2e-16 ***
Exp_2              -0.184617   0.001720 -107.309  < 2e-16 ***
Exp_3              -0.078660   0.001412  -55.718  < 2e-16 ***
Exp_4              -0.031791   0.001030  -30.862  < 2e-16 ***
Birth81            -0.142780   0.001786  -79.939  < 2e-16 ***
Birth78_81         -0.080326   0.001580  -50.835  < 2e-16 ***
Birth75_78         -0.061442   0.001383  -44.416  < 2e-16 ***
Birth72_75         -0.041072   0.001171  -35.068  < 2e-16 ***
Birth69_72         -0.025290   0.000960  -26.343  < 2e-16 ***
factor(YEAR)2009    0.010443   0.001008   10.358  < 2e-16 ***
factor(YEAR)2010   -0.010337   0.001015  -10.188  < 2e-16 ***
factor(YEAR)2011   -0.053650   0.001024  -52.405  < 2e-16 ***
factor(YEAR)2012   -0.051177   0.001028  -49.779  < 2e-16 ***
factor(YEAR)2013   -0.070890   0.001031  -68.749  < 2e-16 ***
factor(YEAR)2014   -0.065899   0.001024  -64.349  < 2e-16 ***
factor(YEAR)2015   -0.035041   0.001016  -34.475  < 2e-16 ***
factor(YEAR)2016   -0.015892   0.001011  -15.723  < 2e-16 ***
factor(YEAR)2017   -0.007154   0.001004   -7.127 1.03e-12 ***
factor(YEAR)2018          NA         NA       NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7947 on 13523268 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3007,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3006 
F-statistic: 1.491e+05 on 39 and 13523268 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: This might be due to details of how your data were coded and processed by the software. For example, which of your groups was considered to be the reference group? Please edit your question to show the function call you made to run this analysis, and which software you used (as choice of reference group can differ among software packages).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've edited the question to include the R code.

Comment: You have a pretty complicated equation. It appears `eligible` is your treatment dummy. And, it appears the variable `y2012` is your post-treatment indicator. But I see you also include industry effects, school effects, and if I’m not mistaken, birth (cohort) effects, to name only a few. The time effects will absorb your post-treatment variable, or you may just lose another year dummy. Could you explain what treatment is in your setting and what the other covariates represent? Or, maybe show us your output. It will be helpful!

Comment: A couple of other points. Try just this first: `lm(logweekwage ~ eligible*y2012, data=data)`. What does your output look like? Then start tossing in covariates. Also, why use `as.factor()` notation for some variables and not others? Also, I recommend naming `y2012` something like `post` or `after` to represent all periods (i.e., years) after treatment is put in place. It is easier on the eyes and it will help you remember what all these variables mean should you take a break from your project. It is common in most disciplines to call this your *post*-treatment variable.

Comment: @ThomasBilach Thanks so much for your comment. Yes, you are right, I included industry, schooling, work experience and birth year cohorts fixed effect. I edited the question to include the regression results based on your suggestions and renamed the `eligible` variable to `treat` and `y2012` to `post` for clarity. 

The reason I didn't use `as.factor()` for some variables is because these variables were originally categorical variables and I lumped several categories under each dummy.

Comment: @ThomasBilach I did as you suggested (tossing in one covariate at a time). With just the interaction term, the coefficient is negative, but turns positive when I use it with industry fixed effect. If I add work experience, the coefficient flips to negative and doesn't change signs when further covariates are added. When I add work experience at the last, the interaction coefficient stays positive until I add work experience. Not sure what to make of this?

EdM's answer answers a lot of my confusion, but if you wanted to chip in I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: @mudir_dokandar If you're presenting these findings, I would recommend juxtaposing your estimates of $\delta$ (i.e., the DiD coefficient) with and without covariates. I wouldn't recommend stepwise throwing in a new set of covariates and repeatedly re-estimating your main interaction term. I'm sure you have a good theoretical basis for including your other measures. It appears your DiD coefficient is insensitive to the inclusion of covariates in the full model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to misinterpret the coefficients in a regression involving interactions. Your regression results agree with the plot.

In standard treatment coding (the default in R), an intercept represents the outcome value when all continuous predictors are at 0 and categorical predictors are at their reference levels. The individual coefficients for non-reference levels of a categorical predictor are the *differences* in outcome from that intercept value when the categorical predictor takes on that level. Following that logic, the coefficient for an interaction term represents the *difference of that difference* when all the predictors in the interaction are at other than reference or 0 levels.

Now look your coding of the predictors in the interaction and at your plot. The reference for `y2012` is years prior to 2012 (left of plot). So the individual coefficient for `eligible` is related to the spread between the two `treatment` curves at early times prior to 2012. The negative coefficient for the interaction term means that the *difference* between the `eligible`/`treatment` groups *decreases* when you go to years after 2012. That's exactly what you see. Yes, the values for the `treatment` group increase with time, but as that happens the *difference between the groups* decreases consistent with the negative coefficient for the interaction term.

*Other notes*

First, you can save yourself a lot of trouble by letting R do much of your coding for you. Rather than setting up a lot of binary variables to represent different levels of a categorical predictor, as you seem to do for `Exp` and `Schl` and birth cohorts (which too easily can lead to a linearly dependent set of predictors), use a single multi-level factor predictor and let R do the necessary work under the hood.

Second, I'm a bit troubled by the way you're handling the `y2012` predictor. If there was some fundamental change in the system that occurred at that date it's fine, but otherwise it looks like the choice of 2012 as a cutoff might have been based on the outcomes as a function of time. That would make inference problematic. Related to that is the observation that the outcomes in the `treatment` group seem to continue to rise over time, something that your model with its categorical break at 2012 doesn't seem to capture. There are ways to have a model find structural breaks in principled ways; do searches on terms like change-point analysis.

Third, there might be some advantage to treating `YEAR` as a continuous rather than a categorical variable. It looks like you have at least 11 year values, so treating it as categorical uses up 10 degrees of freedom. Modeling `YEAR` flexibly, as with a restricted cubic spline, should be able to capture the behavior with respect to `YEAR` while using up only 2 or 3 degrees of freedom.

Fourth, take to heart the recommendations that @ThomasBilach made in comments about naming of variables and presentation. For example, as a reader, I'm still not sure which value of `eligible` represents the `treatment` versus `control` groups here, although this answer doesn't depend on that. And as I get on in years I am amazed at how quickly "obvious" shortcuts in naming things become unintelligible just a few months later, requiring extensive searching through notes.

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted this as the answer. The notes have also been useful. Just a few elaborations: first, the reason I didn't use as.factor() for some variables is because these variables were originally in categorical variables and I lumped  several categories under each mechanically produced dummy. Second, yes, I am trying to see the impact of a program implemented in 2012.

Comment: @mudir_dokandar based on your comment I would suggest modeling the _slopes over time_ before and after 2012, rather than treating YEAR as an unordered categorical variable. The "treatment" that happened in 2012 doesn't suddenly lead to a jump in outcome; rather, its effect seems to grow with time. What you are presently modeling is some type of average effect after 2012, which might be OK to start but doesn't capture the richness of your data over time.

Comment: @EdM You can even help me on this one. For instance, suppose the pre- versus post-treatment trend for the *exposed* group goes from 1 to 4, for a gain of 3. And suppose the pre- versus post-treatment trend for the *unexposed* group goes from 6 to 7 for a gain of 1. This is more or less close to what the OP has plotted. If we use potential outcomes notation, we have $(4-7)-(1-6) = 2$. Or, it could be the differences in changes over time, such as $(4-1)-(7-6) = 2$. In this case the $\delta$ is positive. Do you think this is why most people misinterpret interactions in these settings?

Comment: @ThomasBilach there are so many ways to misinterpret regression coefficients when there are interaction terms that I hesitate to put too much weight on any single one. Your suggestion is certainly one way. My sense from this site is that the most prevalent are not appreciating that: (a) "individual" coefficients represent relationships to outcome when all the _interacting predictors_ are at 0 or reference, and (b) coefficients (under treatment coding) represent _differences_ in outcome associated with predictors. The latter confusion only gets worse for interaction coefficients.